# installing node but missing all packages in node_modules

Tags: node.js, homebrew

On the Mac, after installing node with:

```
brew install node
```

The only package that showed up in /usr/local/lib/node_modules is npm.  My previous installation of node contained a bunch of packages such "express, apn, http2, ws, etc."

Any ideas?

There was not a package.json either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install node you only get `npm`, those other packages you mention, were installed using

```
# probably with sudo
npm install -g {package}
```

The `package.json` is created when you run:

```
npm init
```

It has nothing to do with node installation.

If you wish to start a new project:

```
mkdir project
cd project
npm init
npm install {package-name} {other-package}
```

And now you will have a `node_modules` folder inside `project/` and a `package.json` with `{package-name}` & `{other-package}` as dependencies